# show data label when the values are negative

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I have a bar chart where I'm trying to get the data labels to show. When the values are all positive the data labels appear fine. When I mix in some negative values, the datalabels don't show:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%"
           creationComplete="fillArray();"
           >

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.events.Event;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        public var array:Object=new Object();
        [Bindable]
        public var ac:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection([]);

        private function fillArray():void{

            array=new Object(); 
            ac=new ArrayCollection([]);

            for(var k:int=-12; k<10; k++){ //datalabels are visible if I start k at 0
            array=new Object();
            array['val']=k;
            array['label']=k;
            ac.addItem(array);
            }



        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:BarChart id="barChart" width="100%" dataProvider="{ac}">
    <mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:CategoryAxis dataProvider="{ac}" categoryField="label"/>
    </mx:verticalAxis>
    <mx:series>
        <mx:BarSeries xField="val" labelPosition="outside"/>

    </mx:series>
</mx:BarChart>
```

EDIT: Is this a bug in Flex and (therefore) unanswerable?

Comment: This sounds like he same problem as in your previous question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161891/showing-negative-values-in-a-bar-chart Is it? If so, it is proper etiquette to modify the previous question with new information / code and not post a new one.

Comment: no. This one is asking for datalabels. I forgot I still had that one posted...I figured that one out. I deleted it. thx

Comment: @user657821 If you figured the previous one out; the proper etiquette is to answer your own question; so that folks can find the solution in the future; not to delete the question.

Comment: I've been told NOT to answer my own questions, which is why I deleted it.

Comment: besides, if you use this code I have in this question, it answers my prior question. thx

Comment: @user657821 You were misinforned in terms of StackOverflow etiquette.  I think there is even a special badge for answering your own question.  The code here; even if it contains the solution to your previous question, may not help others trying to answer the previous question because the context is different.  Oh, well, at least you know for the future.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll do that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that this is a problem of size, with 22 bars the label are too small to see, so they don't show.
if you change the range of the "for" to:

```
for(var k:int=-5; k<5; k++)
```

you should be able to see all the labels of the chart.